# How to find intersection of a set of polyhedrons?

Tags: convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, polyhedra, convex-geometry

Let's say a polyhedron is defined as follows:

$$P = \{x|a_j^Tx\leq b_j, j=1,...,m \quad c_j^Tx=d_j, j=1,...,p\}$$.

[image: enter image description here----------------------------]

I have a set of polyhedrons which were defined as above in 3D. I want to find the intersection of those as one polyhedron whose redundant equalities and inequalities should be removed. Any suggestions on this really appreciated.

Comment: Just combine all the inequalities and equalities in one set...??

Comment: @ShubhamJohri but how to remove redundant inequalities and equalities?

Comment: @GPrathap If this is part of your question then you should include it into the post. Otherwise the answer of Shubham is correct and is exactly what you can expect.

Comment: @M.Winter sure thanks